# Retrieve all records sharing duplicate value from a column

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I would like to return all records from a table that share duplicate values from a given specific column, in this case the BIN column.

```
Create table #TempCompany (CompanyID varchar(6), Name varchar(50),BIN varchar(6))
Insert into #TempCompany (CompanyID,Name,BIN) 

SELECT '000001','ABC Company','000000' Union All
SELECT '000002','DEF Company','000001' Union All
SELECT '000003','GHI Company','000001' Union All
SELECT '000004','JKL Company','000002' Union All
SELECT '000005','LMN Company','000003' Union All
SELECT '000006','OPQ Company','000003' Union All
SELECT '000007','RST Company','000003'

Drop Table #TempCompany
```

I would like to return this result:

```
CompanyID   Name    BIN
000002  DEF Company 000001
000003  GHI Company 000001
000005  LMN Company 000003
000006  OPQ Company 000003
000007  RST Company 000003
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using window functions:

```
select tc.*
from (select tc.*,
             count(*) over (partition by bin) as cnt
      from #TempCompany tc
     ) tc
where cnt >= 2;
```

Comment: This seems to accomplish my goal but not sure between you and @mureinik which is the best answer but I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing this is with a subquery that uses a `having` clause to locate such records:

```
SELECT *
FROM   #TempCompany
WHERE  BIN IN (SELECT   BIN
               FROM     #TempCompany
               GROUP BY BIN
               HAVING   COUNT(*) > 1)
```

Comment: This seems to accomplish my goal but not sure between you and @Gordon Linoff which is the best answer but I appreciate it.